# What is the actual science behind the new-gen technologies namely Snicko & Hotspot?

Tags: cricket, technology

Well, just like any other Indian, I also happen to be a big cricket fan! Getting straight to the point here, I just want to know something in detail about the technologies namely the '***Snicko*** and '***Hotspot***', which are being used right now to make sure there are seldom umpiring errors. 

Hotspot has started getting negative comments stating some fault, I'd like to know about these two in detail.

Answer (score 2):

**Snicko**

> A Snickometer, commonly known as Snicko, is used in televising cricket
>   to graphically analyse sound and video, and show whether a fine noise,
>   or snick, occurs as ball passes bat.
>
> The Snickometer is often used in a slow motion television replay by
>   the third umpire to determine if the cricket ball touched the cricket
>   bat on the way through to the wicketkeeper. The commentators will
>   listen and view the shape of the recorded soundwave. If there is a
>   sound of leather on willow, which is usually a short sharp sound in
>   synchrony with the ball passing the bat, then the ball has touched the
>   bat. Other sounds such as the ball hitting the batsman's pads, or the
>   bat hitting the pitch, and so on, tend to have a fatter shape on the
>   sound waveform.

**HotSpot**

> Hot Spot is an infra-red imaging system used in to determine whether
>   the ball has struck the batsman, bat or pad. Hot Spot requires two
>   infra-red cameras on opposite sides of the ground above the field of
>   play that are continuously recording an image. Any suspected snick or
>   bat/pad event can be verified by examining the infrared image, which
>   usually shows a bright spot where contact friction from the ball has
>   elevated the local temperature. Where referrals to an off-field third
>   umpire are permitted, the technology is used to enhance the on-field
>   umpire's decision-making accuracy. Where referrals are not permitted,
>   the technology is used primarily as an analysis aid for televised
>   coverage.
>
> Hot Spot uses two infra-red cameras positioned at either end of the
>   ground.[4] These cameras sense and measure heat from friction
>   generated by a collision, such as ball on pad, ball on bat, ball on
>   ground or ball on glove. Using a subtraction technique a series of
>   black-and-white negative frames is generated into a computer,
>   precisely localising the ball's point of contact.

**Resources:**

Snicko meter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snickometer

Hot Spot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Spot_(cricket)